# trouble getting content from my database to a form in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

I have been follwing a series of tutorials over at [thedigitalcraft.com][1] building my first ever dynamic website. I recently followed his 15th, and thought I followed along greatly, but for some reason the content that should be showing up isn't when I run the page. No errors, its almost like one of my sql statements is wrong, or it can't connect to my phpMyAdmin database.I'm building a user interface for editing each of the pages, a control panel. I'm running on XAMPP localhost btw, working in dreamweaver. Why is my content not showing up in the form? I know that I am connected to the database.. I've pasted my code from my pages.php and index.php

```
1. pages.php:

<?php ## Page Manager ?>

<h2>Page Manager</h2>

<div class="col sidebar">

    <ul>

        <?php

           $q = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY name ASC"; 
           $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

           if ($r)
           {
                while($link = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
                {
                    echo '<li><a href="?page=pages&id='.$link['id'].'">'.$link['name'].'</a></li>';
                }
           }

        ?>

    </ul>

</div>

<div class="col editor">

    <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

            $q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = '$_GET(id)' LIMIT 1";
           // the database connection, our query
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $opened = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

    ?>

        <form action="#" method="post">

            <p><label>Page title: </label><input type="text" size="30" name="title" value="<?php echo $opened['title']?>"></p>
            <p><label>Page name:</label> <input type="text" size="30" name="name" value="<?php echo $opened['name']?>"></p> 

            <label>Page body:</label><br>
            <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="8"><?php echo $opened['body'] ?></textarea>

        </form>

    <?php } ?>

</div>

index.php:

<?php
error_reporting(0);
// Setup document:
include('config/setup.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php //echo $page_title; ?>JakeForDesign - Admin Panel</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrap_overall">

    <div class="header"> <?php head(); ?> </div>

    <div class="nav_main"> <?php nav_main(); ?> </div>

    <div class="content"> <?php include('content/'.$pg.'.php'); ?> </div>

    <div class="footer"> <?php footer(); ?> </div>

</div>    

</body>
</html>

2. index.php:

<?php
error_reporting(0);
// Setup document:
include('config/setup.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php //echo $page_title; ?>JakeForDesign - Admin Panel</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrap_overall">

    <div class="header"> <?php head(); ?> </div>

    <div class="nav_main"> <?php nav_main(); ?> </div>

    <div class="content"> <?php include('content/'.$pg.'.php'); ?> </div>

    <div class="footer"> <?php footer(); ?> </div>

</div>    

</body>
</html>

3. setup.php(for connection to database)

<?php
## Setup Document

// host(or location of the database), username, //password, database name

$dbc = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database') OR die ('Could not connect to the database because: '. mysqli_connect_error() );

include('Functions/sandbox.php');
include('Functions/template.php');

if ($_GET['page'] == '')
{
    $pg = 'home';       
}
else
{
    $pg = $_GET['page'];
}

$page_title = get_page_title($dbc, $pg);

?>
```

Comment: are you navigating to `index.php?page=pages`?

Comment: it looks like you are missing an include in your pages.php to your setup.php file

Comment: $_GET(id) should be $_GET['id'] and you should definitely sanitize your input. You can look into prepared statements. also, use @ sparingly. You shouldn't be suppressing errors. Instead avoid generating errors to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = '$_GET(id)' LIMIT 1";
```

This is wrong

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "' LIMIT 1";
```

This is good

Don't forget to secure it with intval() if it's a numeric value!

Comment: While intval will strip down to numbers, it is still better to suggest prepared statements. Also breaking out of string is identical to leaving it the way it was since double quotes will parse the variable as expected.

Comment: OMG how STUPID of ME! Hours wasted on just that little error HAHA! THANKS GUYS!! Especialy zeflex and kai Qing. I will look into using prepared statements as well.